# Solving a slow query with a Foreignkey that has isnull=False and order_by in a Django ListView

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys

I have a Django [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) that allows to paginate through 'active' People.

The (simplified) models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    # ...
    active_schedule = models.ForeignKey('Schedule', related_name='+', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Schedule(models.Model):
    field = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    # ...
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='schedules', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The Person table contains almost 700.000 rows and the Schedule table contains just over 2.000.000 rows (on average every Person has 2-3 Schedule records, although many have none and a lot have more). For an 'active' Person, the `active_schedule` ForeignKey is set, of which there are about 5.000 at any time.

The ListView is supposed to show all active Person's, sorted by `field` on Schedule (and some other conditions, that don't seem to matter for this case).

The query then becomes:

```
Person.objects
    .filter(active_schedule__isnull=False)
    .select_related('active_schedule')
    .order_by('active_schedule__field')
```

Specifically the order_by on the related field makes this query terribly slow (that is: it takes about a second, which is too slow for a web app).

I was hoping the `filter` condition would select the 5000 records, which then become relatively easily sortable. But when I run explain on this query, it shows that the (Postgres) database is messing with many more rows:

```
Gather Merge  (cost=224316.51..290280.48 rows=565366 width=227)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Sort  (cost=223316.49..224023.19 rows=282683 width=227)
        Sort Key: exampledb_schedule.field
        ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=89795.12..135883.20 rows=282683 width=227)
              Hash Cond: (exampledb_person.active_schedule_id = exampledb_schedule.id)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on exampledb_person  (cost=0.00..21263.03 rows=282683 width=161)
                    Filter: (active_schedule_id IS NOT NULL)
              ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=67411.27..67411.27 rows=924228 width=66)
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on exampledb_schedule  (cost=0.00..67411.27 rows=924228 width=66)
```

I recently changed the models to be this way. In a previous version I had a model with just the ~5.000 active Person's in it. Doing the order_by on this small table was considerably faster! I am hoping to achieve the same speed with the current models.

I tried retrieving just the fields needed for the Listview (using `values`) which does help a little, but not much. I also tried setting the related_name on `active_schedule` and approaching the problem from Schedule, but that makes no difference. I tried putting a `db_index` on the `Schedule.field`, but that seems only to make things slower. Conditional queries also did not help (although I probably have not tried all possibilities). I'm at a loss.

The SQL statement generated by the ORM query:

```
SELECT 
    "exampledb_person"."id", 
    "exampledb_person"."name", 
    ...
    "exampledb_person"."active_schedule_id", 
    "exampledb_person"."created", 
    "exampledb_person"."updated", 
    "exampledb_schedule"."id", 
    "exampledb_schedule"."person_id", 
    "exampledb_schedule"."field", 
    ...
    "exampledb_schedule"."created", 
    "exampledb_schedule"."updated" 
FROM 
    "exampledb_person" 
INNER JOIN 
    "exampledb_schedule" 
ON ("exampledb_person"."active_schedule_id" = "exampledb_schedule"."id") 
WHERE 
    "exampledb_person"."active_schedule_id" IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 
    "exampledb_schedule"."field" ASC
```

(Some fields were left out, for simplicity.)

Is it possible to speed up this query, or should I revert back to using a special Model for the active Person's?

**EDIT:** When I change the query, just for comparison/testing, to sort on an UNindexed field on `Person`, the query is equally show. However, if I then add an index to that field, the query is fast! I had to try this, as the SQL statement indeed shows that it's ordering on `"exampledb_schedule"."field"` - a field without index, but like I said: adding an index on the field makes no difference.

**EDIT:** I suppose it's also worth noting that when trying a much simpler sort query directly on Schedule, either on an indexed field or not, it's MUCH faster. For instance, for this test I've added an index to `Schedule.field`, then the following query is blazing fast:

```
Schedule.objects.order_by('field')
```

Somewhere in here lies the solution...

Comment: Can you add the SQL statement generated by that Django ORM query?

Comment: Is there an index on `active_schedule_id`?

Comment: Also, why do you have a foreign key to `Person` in `Schedule`?

Comment: Yes, Django creates an index for foreign keys automatically: `"exampledb_person_active_schedule_id_a9330fcf" btree (active_schedule_id)`. The foreign key to `Person` in `Schedule` exists there to show `Schedule`'s for a `Person`. The `active_schedule` FK is there for easy access. Another way would be to have a boolean field on `Schedule`, like `is_active`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments by @[guarav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5814042/gaurav-waghmare) and my edits pointed me in the direction of the solution, which was staring in my face for a while...

The filter clause in my questions - `filter(active_schedule__isnull=False)` - seems to invalidate the database indexes. I wasn't aware of this, and had hoped a database expert would point me in this direction.

The solution is to filter on `Schedule.field`, which is 0 for inactive Person records and >0 for active ones:

```
Person.objects
    .select_related('active_schedule')
    .filter(active_schedule__field__gte=1)
    .order_by('active_schedule__field')
```

This query properly uses the indexes and is fast (20ms opposed to ~1000ms).